# How to pass id to the function to remove items from the list

Tags: python, flask

I am working on removing items from the basket, but when I click the button 'remove' it takes all the items from the basket and remove them all. How I can make it so the function takes only id for the item I want to delete?

```
@phones.route('/delete_cart',  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delete_cart():
    items = [j for i in session["cart"] for j in i]
    for item in items:
        phone = get_phone_by_id(item)
        print([phone.id])
        session['cart'].remove([phone.id])
        session.modified = True

    return redirect(url_for('main.phones'))
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr><th>Phone Name</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th><th>Total</th><th></th></tr>
{% for key, phone in display_cart.items() %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ phone["brand"] }} {{ phone["model"] }}</td>
        <td>{{ phone["qty"] }}</td>
        <td>£{{ "%.2f" % phone["price"] }}</td>
        <td>£{{ "%.2f" % (phone["qty"] * phone["price"])}}</td>
        <td><a href="{{ url_for('phones.delete_cart', id=phone.id) }}">Remove</a></td></tr> 
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following your previous question [Removing item from list python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54845800/removing-item-from-list-python), the method should be like this.

```
@phones.route('/delete_cart/id',  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delete_cart(id):
    phone = next(item for item in session['cart'] if item['id'] == id)
    print(phone)
    session['cart'].remove(phone)
    session.modified = True

    return redirect(url_for('main.phones'))
```

Comment: when i run the code i got an error: `TypeError: delete_cart2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'`

Answer (score 1):

The route should look like this:

```
@phones.route('/delete_cart/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delete_cart(id):
```

The  indicates that the id is an integer variable.

Comment: when I enter the cart I got an error: `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'id'`, looks like this line is triggering it `<td><a href="{{ url_for('phones.delete_cart2', id=phone.id) }}">Remove</a></td></tr>`

Comment: Your function name is phones.delete_cart2?
Also could you please write an example of a phone dictionary?

Comment: Yes that's the name of the function, that's my phone dict: `dict_of_phones[phone] = {
                    "id": phone.id,
                    "qty":1,
                    "model": phone.model,
                    "price": phone.price,
                    "brand": phone.brand.name
                }`

Comment: In python the is key's value must be referenced like this: phone['id'] not like phone.id
Jinja can use the phone.id version

Comment: I am using Jinja

Comment: I understand that, but this part is in Python:

@phones.route('/delete_cart',  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delete_cart():
    items = [j for i in session["cart"] for j in i]
    for item in items:
        phone = get_phone_by_id(item)
        print([phone.id])
        session['cart'].remove([phone.id])

And phone.id should be used as phone['id']

Comment: dosnt work line with phone['id], triggers an error `TypeError: 'Phone' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would add your `id` parameter in your route and access it directly.

```
@phones.route('/delete_cart/id',  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delete_cart(id):
```